# Sinatra Net::HTTP causes timeouts on a simple request

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

I have a small simple `Net::HTTP` POST request to do to my Sinatra app:

```
def collect(website)
    uri = URI("http://localhost:9393/save/#{website}")
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
    puts res.body
end
```

But it causes a timeout. Here is the request handler:

```
post '/save/:website' do |website|
    puts request.body
    "done"
end
```

I never reach the `puts` nor the `done`. My `shotgun` server is running on port 9393 of course. When I use the REST Console extension and paste valid json in it, it works for that same path.

What is causing this Timeout::Error?

Comment: Are you setting the `website` variable? Try printing out the `website` in your sinatra action.

Comment: also i think it's jure `request.body` no need for the `.read` part
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object

Comment: @spullen I'm sure it's not the `request.body.read` part, because that works in the REST Console extension. Also, the `request.body` is a `StringIO` object, just read your own link. It says so 2 lines down.

Comment: I'm aware, just looking at all possibilities.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger (https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) to see what's going on right before the `puts` statement?

Comment: How about trying the post method http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

Comment: @spullen The debugger simply shows a timeout error at the `res` variable. Nothing else.

Comment: Is the `website` variable a URI as well?

Comment: Yes. I fixed it by the way, by ditching `shotgun` and just using `sinatra/reloader`. It worked immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the weird thing is, I changed my server from `shotgun` to simply running it with `sinatra` and the gem `sinatra/reloader`. I was using `shotgun` because it would auto reload whenever the source file changed, and `sinatra` itself didn't.

After ditching `shotgun`, it worked straight away.