# Thin post request not working

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra, thin

I have a Thin server that runs a Sinatra app. In one file, I send a POST request, but it never arrives to its route. The same code works if I run it with `bundle exec ruby myapp.rb` but when it's run by Thin using `bundle exec thin start -p 3000`, it simply does not match the post route.

```
post '/save/:website' do |website|
    website_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    puts "Saving #{website} plugin data" #never reaches here

    persister = Persister.new
    persister.update_or_persist(website_data)

    body "success"
end
```

And this is how I declare the POST request

```
def send_result (path, result)
    request      = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/save/something', initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
    request.body = result.to_json
    response     = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', '3000').start { |http| http.request(request) }
end
```

Here is the `config.ru`

```
# config.ru
require "./myapp"
run Sinatra::Application
```

I never reach the `puts` in my post route, but I do reach it when it's deployed without `thin`. Why does this request not work?

Also, [I had already opened another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641970/sinatra-nethttp-causes-timeouts-on-a-simple-request), but this time I really need the Thin server because I will use Apache to proxy to Thin.

Comment: Try `warn "request.body = #{request.body}"` as the first line in the route and see if that prints anything to the console when running via Thin.

Comment: It does nothing. Nothing puts into console or views up on the pages.

Comment: Next step I'd try would be to request the route with something non-Ruby like `curl -X POST http://localhost:4567/save/something` and see if that gets a response of any kind from the server.

Comment: Do you have a `config.ru` file? What does it look like?

Comment: @iain it does work like that. and config.ru also posted

Comment: What does your full `myapp.rb` file look like? Are you using the Sinatra modular style or classic?

Comment: @matt i'm using classic style, just simply defining the routes. But my issue is not with Sinatra, as everything works when I'm not using `thin`.

Comment: If you were using the modular style, then `run Sinatra::Application` in your `config.ru` would explain the routes missing. Also if Thin is in your `Gemfile` (which it must be for `bundle exec thin start` to work) then `bundle exec ruby myapp.rb` will normally use Thin as well (unless you override this by setting the `server` option).

Comment: Try using `rackup` instead of `thin` because if Thin is in the Gemfile (as @matt says) Sinatra will automatically use that as the handler, so `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 3000` might work better, or you can force the use of Thin with `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 3000 -s thin`. As an aside, if you install the gems via `bundle install --binstubs` you can drop the `bundle exec` and that last command would be `bin/rackup config.ru -p 3000 -s thin`, much nicer to type! :)